# Fastest way to insert 1M + items into Sequel (Sqlite) db?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel

I have a Sqlite database that I'm using Ruby's Sequel to insert data into.

When  attempting to insert 1M+ items it seems to be quite slow.

The code I'm using to do this is below.

```
DB[:my_table].multi_insert to_insert
```

Are there any faster ways to do this? Am I missing something?

Comment: How long does it take?

Comment: @NiklasB. 4-5 minutes

Comment: Have you tried disabling some of the safety features temporarily?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite

Comment: @NiklasB. No, how can that be achieved?

Comment: I had to look for the link first, see my comment above

Comment: @NiklasB. I'm not sure how that link applies to this question because it doesn't have any Ruby code in it. I don't really know C.

Comment: The relevant parts are the sql pragmas and the suggestion to use prepared statements (which sequel probably does already)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I got better performance wrapping the code in a transaction.

```
DB.transaction do
    DB[:my_table].multi_insert to_insert
end
```

I'm not satisfied that this is as fast as it can be, but it runs in just over 2 mins now, which *should* be Ok. Oh well, case closed.

Comment: You should definitely try `PRAGMA synchronous=off` and `PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY` in addition to that. Also, if your table has an index, consider removing it and recreating it *after* the bulk insert. You can read more about SQLite tuning in [the FAQ](http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html)